Payment Gateway Integration with Django
I'm integrating payment gateway APIs in my application (Django). I have written a class PaymentGateway that provides all the methods for all payment related utility. The __init__ initialises the payment gateway client as self.client so that it's available across all methods. But, I need help in making a decision on how to use it.
Is it OK if I instantiate and use the payment gateway object across the program, whenever I need it?
OR
Should I maintain a single instance of it across the whole application?
Need help in understanding what could be pros and cons or any other suggestion so that I can make this decision.
My current code looks something like below right now:
class PaymentGateway:
    def __init__(self):
        self.client = PG(api_key="api_key")

    def create_intent(self, user):
        return self.client.intents.create(customer_id=user.email)

    def get_user_id(email):
        return self.client.users.retrieve(customer_id=email)

class MyView(GenericAPIView):
    def get(self, request):
        pg_instance = PaymentGateway()
        intent = pg_instance.create(request.user)
        return Response({"user_id": get_user_id(request.user), "intent": intent})


# Somewhere in utils.py
def get_user_id(user):
    pg = PaymentGateway()
    return pg.get_user_id(user.email)


